# myworkout: Property does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

Got a problem. everything is fine except for this line of code:

```
"this.workoutService.deleteWorkout(workoutId).subscribe(data => {
       this.result = data;"
```

Specifically, "workoutService"...it says "Property 'workoutService' does not exist on type 'WorkoutDetailsPage'."

from this code (WorkoutDetailsPage):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { WorkoutService } from '../../app/services/workout.service';
import { WorkoutsPage } from '../workouts/workouts'

@Component({
selector: 'workout-details',
templateUrl: 'workout-details.html'
})
export class WorkoutDetailsPage {
public workout: any;
public result: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params:NavParams, workoutService:WorkoutService) {
    this.workout = params.get('workout');
}

deleteWorkout(workoutId){
    this.workoutService.deleteWorkout(workoutId).subscribe(data => {
       this.result = data;
    });

    this.navCtrl.push(WorkoutsPage);
  }
}
```

The outcome is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEzMU.png)

Comment: For future reference, it is probably best not to use images for code snippets.   Just paste the code into the StackOverflow editor, highlight it, and click on the code button. It makes it more readable for those helping you and we can also copy from the snippets to give our answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any parameters to the constructor that do not have access modifiers will not be added as a class member. Simply add `private` or `public` to your workout service parameter in the constructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params: NavParams, private workoutService: WorkoutService)
```